# Are scratches on a MacBook covered under warranty?

Tags: macbook-pro

I found this tiny deep scratch on my MBP and I don't know how the heck did it get there. Is there way to fix it or does my warranty cover it?

It is near the ESC also near the charger input.

Comment: where on you machine? Screen top of lid, bottom, near keyboard?

Comment: Updated my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warranty generally excludes any scratches to the machine as they are normally cosmetic issue that arise from normal wear and tear as opposed to a functional defect. By extension, Apple Protection Plan will not cover it since it generally follows the warranty guidelines but for a longer time.

You could always ask for service - especially if there is some functional concern like usability or you want a second opinion if the device was made properly. I have had things covered like where a hairline crack could be something that would fail to protect the insides (on an iPhone) so it wouldn't hurt to ask even if you are aware the answer may be no.

Answer (score -2):

Warranty covers it

After Warranty period is over, get Apple Protection Plan too.

Comment: Since when does Apple cover cosmetic damage?

Comment: Also, you can only take out AppleCare during the 1st year of warranty. AppleCare adds two years from the original date of purchase, not from the date that AppleCare was purchased.